# 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryBoard' in bundle NSBundle

Tags: xcode

I have looked at many answers for my issue i've tired them all, heres my error, this is annoying me big time.

Simulator = 5.0 and target = 5.0

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryBoard' in bundle NSBundle

Not sure why theres any reference of that file above.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you started the project with the option "Use Storyboard" checked during creation.

Select the target and check the "Summary" tab if there's an entry for "Main Storyboard". If, delete it and make sure to set the appropriate XIB for "Main Interface".